# Increasing text size in li attribute

Tags: jsp

I have the below snippet of code and I want to increase the font size of the text inside

tag. How can i achieve the same?

```
<tr style="height:18px; background:url(docs/images/dots_horiz.gif) top repeat-x #E3E8DE;">
          <td style="padding-left:7px;"> 
          <strong><u><i>APPLICATION TEST</i></u> - </strong>
          <span title="header=[Application Test] body=[Use the dropdown to select an application rating of 'Pass', 'Fail','I Do Not Use This','No Longer in Use' or 'Not In Scope':<br>
             <ul> 
               <li>Pass - Able to operate the application </li> 
               <li>Fail - Unable to use the application (i.e. not on the machine, error message pop-up) </li>
               <li>I Do Not Use This - Tester does not use this application </li> 
               <li>No Longer in Use - This application is no longer in use by <strong>anyone</strong> in the tester's group.<strong>Tester should consult their BU Coordinator before selecting this response. </strong></li>
               <li>Not In Scope - This application is not in scope for testing by tester </li></ul>]"> 
                   <a href="#"><img src="docs/images/btn_blue_help.png"
            align="absmiddle" border="0"></a></span>&nbsp;Tester is to ensure that critical <i><u>Applications listed in BizCon plan</u></i> are tested accordingly<br></br>
          - Tester to log into critical applications and confirm basic functionality<br>
          - Tester to validate market data connectivity (if applicable)
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using inline css you'll have to apply the value on `<ul>` like so `<ul style="font-size: 12px">` for a global overrwrite.

If you want to apply different sizes on `<li>` you'll have to define the value on each `<li>`